# Why are the symbols of some constants eliminated in certain equations when we assign them the value 1?

Tags: symbols, physics, equation, units-of-measurement, simplification

For example, in the expression of the gamma factor in special relativity we make c = 1 because the units are not important, but when c is suppressed from the equation

Gamma = 1 / SQRT (1 - (v / c) ^ 2)
it remains:
Gamma = 1 / SQRT (1 - v ^ 2) which is dimensionally wrong.

The same is true when we set tha Planck constant h = 1 in others equations.

Why do physicists use dimensionally incorrect equations?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that they don't use incorrect equations. When you use a different set of units such as natural units where c=1, the dimensions are also different now. Everything is expressed in terms of Energy. c=1 implies velocity is dimensionless. Thus, in your example, v is dimensionless and the equation is well behaved.